# Seems like nginx proxy server doen't work

Tags: nginx, asp.net-core

I'm newbie in linux and nginx hosting. I have a simple asp net core app that I need to run on https://localhost:5050. So I send a request on https://localhost and wait that nginx process it to :5050 port. But it doesn't..

I created \etc\nginx\sites-available\aspnetcore.conf with the following code

```
server {
    listen 443;

    location / {
        proxy_pass https://localhost:5050; 
        proxy_http_version 1.1;
        proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
        proxy_set_header Connection keep-alive;
        proxy_set_header Host $host;
        proxy_cache_bypass $http_upgrade;
    }
}
```

and a symbolinc link to /etc/nginx/sites-enabled/aspnetcore.conf.
Also I have in Startup.cs file

```
app.UseForwardedHeaders(new ForwardedHeadersOptions
{
    ForwardedHeaders = ForwardedHeaders.XForwardedFor | ForwardedHeaders.XForwardedProto
});
```

So my app doesn't get any request. What am I doing wrong?

**UPD:**
The problem in https contact. I configured ssl as it describes here
https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-create-a-self-signed-ssl-certificate-for-nginx-on-debian-9
But still there are no requests...

Comment: Anything in the error logs of nginx? `/var/log/nginx/error_log.log`

Comment: Try to make your ASP.NET Core App listen on  `0.0.0.0:5050` instead of `localhost:5050`

Comment: @Baklap4 
2019/01/18 09:18:45 [alert] 553#553: *2 open socket #13 left in connection 3
2019/01/18 09:18:45 [alert] 553#553: *5 open socket #14 left in connection 4
2019/01/18 09:18:45 [alert] 553#553: aborting

Comment: @itminus 
The same result

Answer (score 0):

```
upstream backend {
    server localhost:5050;
}

server {
    listen 443;

    location / {
        proxy_pass http://backend;
        proxy_http_version 1.1;
        proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
        proxy_set_header Connection keep-alive;
        proxy_set_header Host $host;
        proxy_cache_bypass $http_upgrade;
    }
}
```

Comment: does not help, the same